# i have an issue accessing env variables in NodeJS

Tags: node.js

Well, i have 3 types of environments (i.e development,test,production) am using nodejs with express. My problem is this my either development and production scripts don't run because they can't access .env variables i have searched online but i can't find something helpful. This is what i did i created .env file and put my variables in. i tried using export command i.e `export key=value`. please help

I created a .env file and added either of development database url and production database url, but when i run either of environment it doesn't work. i also tried using export command `export key=value`. but it works for a while and then it fails again.

```
//my config
require('dotenv').config();
module.exports ={
    development :{
        use_env_variable: process.env.DEVELOPMENT_URL,
        dialect: 'postgres'
    },
    production :{
        use_env_variable:process.env.PRODUCTION_URL,
        dialect: 'postgres',

    }
}
```

```
//my package.json scripts

{
  "name": "report_deck",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "export NODE_ENV=production && sequelize db:migrate && node ./build/index.js",
    "dev": "nodemon --exec babel-node ./api/index.js",
    "test": "export NODE_ENV=test &&  sequelize db:migrate:undo:all  && sequelize db:migrate  && nyc --require @babel/register  mocha ./api/test/test.js --timeout 20000 --exit",
    "build": "rm -rf ./build && babel -d ./build ./api -s",
    "generate-lcov": "nyc report --reporter=text-lcov > lcov.info",
    "coveralls-coverage": "coveralls < lcov.info",
    "codeclimate-coverage": "codeclimate-test-reporter < lcov.info",
    "coverage": "nyc npm test && npm run generate-lcov && npm run coveralls-coverage && npm run codeclimate-coverage"
  },

}
```

```
//.env
DEVELOPMENT_URL=postgres://example1:pass@example:5432/dbname
PRODUCTION_URL=postgres://example2:pass@example:5432/dbname
```

```
//my index.js
import express from 'express';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import classRoutes from './server/routes/classRouter';
// all routes
import cors from 'cors';
const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cors());
//use all routes
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

const port = process.env.PORT || 8003;

app.get('*', (req, res) => res.status(200).send({
    message: "Entrance"
}));

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log("Entrance done, We are running at port " + port);
});


export default app;
```

Expectations:
It should log "entrance done we are running on port 8003" for (npm run dev)
It should log "entrance done we are running on port 5000" for(heroku local web)
Actual:
throw new TypeError('Parameter "url" must be a string, not ' + typeof url);

Comment: Hopefully those keys you posted are fake.

Comment: @ggorlen it is not fake

Answer (score 0):

You should add `-r dotenv/config` to your starting script to preload dotenv =>

```
    "start": "export NODE_ENV=production && sequelize db:migrate && node -r dotenv/config ./build/index.js",
```

Check [docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv)